# Truncating a txt file by 'x' bytes in C#

Tags: c#, byte, line, filestream, truncate

I want to get rid of the last line of a text file after reading the contents.  The text files are quite large, so Reading/Writing is not an option due to performance issues.

My current idea is to calculate the number of bytes the last line represents (along with the carry return) and truncate the file.

A lot of the options I saw referred to using "Filestream.setLength()", and I am confused as to how this works.

Wouldn't this just write the file back, but stop the file at a certain number of bytes, since the 'read' function reads in the bytes, and writes them back to a buffer? Or would I be able to use this function as I am reading, and move the "end position" of the text file back, say 24 bytes?

This is the current code I am using

```
try
            { 
            //reading
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //gets the line
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (!line.StartsWith("KeyWord", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            //add number of lines
                            lineCount += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Finds the occurence of the first numbers in a string
                            string resultString = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value;
                            long lastLineBytes = 0;
                            foreach (char c in line)
                            {
                                //each char takes up 1 byte
                                lastLineBytes++;         
                            }
                            //carriage return
                            lastLineBytes += 2;
                            long fileLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
                            Trace.WriteLine("The length of the file is " + fileLength);

                            //the size of the file - the last line
                            //truncate at this byte position, and we will be done. 
                            long newFileLength = fileLength - lastLineBytes;
                            //Truncation goes ehre
                        }
                }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx

Comment: I read through this and I am still having trouble understanding how I could use this in a practice. Do you have any examples of this in use I could check out?

Comment: I cant assure but I belive that changing the size of the stream will only change the file table indexes to point just to the left bytes, create a test program which is really simple and test it, that's your best chance.

Comment: @Gusman I just tested it out, and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: @Gusman is there anyway that I can use Filestream to get the contents of the text file? Or would I have to use a Streamwriter to be able to actually get the contents in a String format?

Comment: yes, read it as an array of bytes and then use System.Text.Encoding.(the file encoding).GetString(theReadBytes);

Comment: @Gusman awesome, thank you so much! If you put one of these comments as an actual answer, I will gladly declare it.

Comment: @Gusman I tried with bigger and bigger files, and I am getting a System.OutOfMemoryException.  Should I reduce my buffer size, or how do I combat this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, can you explain a bit what's your goal? depending on what you want to do there are different options, also, if your file is encoded in UTF8 which has a variable char size using an arbitrary length for the array will break the content.

Comment: All I want to do right now is get the number of lines in the text file, and then compare it with the last line of the text file and then truncate that last line.  It was working fine with smallish text files, but I tried with a ~2gb text file and it gave me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the size of the stream it will rewrite just the file table indexes to point just to the left bytes.

For your second question, yes, you can use this to read the content (in this example I assumed ASCII encoding, use the appropiate encoder).

```
FileStream str = //get the stream
byte[] data = new byte[str.Length];
str.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
string theContent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

Comment: ASCII isn't a very good assumption because it is not common in this context and is in direct opposition to the UTF--8 that the code in the question uses. See [StreamReader(Stream stream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TomBlodget That's if the file is created by .net. Also, any assumption is bad, because that I stated to change it to the correct encoder, ASCII is the historically standard for text files, yes, nowadays it's most usual to find UTF8, but ancient customs are hard to change and I'm programming for 30 years, so text files for me still are ASCII XD.